# Getting a number from pubchem site with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pubchem

I'm doing a search on the pubchem site with the code below. I need to get the "Compound CID:" number from the screen from the search result but I couldn't get it. I need help on this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = "https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/"
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
searchInput = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input")
searchInput.click()
searchInput.send_keys("75-05-8")
searchInput.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(2)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the text ***6342***  you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *css_selector* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-label^='Featured Compound Result Secondary Link; Position:1; Page:1'] > span.breakword > span").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@data-label, 'Featured Compound Result Secondary Link; Position:1; Page:1')]/span[@class='breakword']/span").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='text'][id^='search']"))).send_keys("75-05-8" + Keys.RETURN)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-label^='Featured Compound Result Secondary Link; Position:1; Page:1'] > span.breakword > span"))).text)
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text'][starts-with(@id, 'search')]"))).send_keys("75-05-8" + Keys.RETURN)
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@data-label, 'Featured Compound Result Secondary Link; Position:1; Page:1')]/span[@class='breakword']/span"))).text)
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  6342
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very important for me. I have an intermediate level of knowledge. I will look at the documents you provided. Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I mean you used time.sleep() and a depreciated driver.find_by_xpath() also you don't seem to have Service as well.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Where did ya find _`time.sleep()`_ and _`driver.find_by_xpath()`_ in my answer :/

Comment: Not you debanjan